# In Taylor series, is the last term greater than remainder term?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

For Taylor expansion, we have
\begin{equation}
f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{f^{''}(x_0)}{2 !}(x-x_0)^{2}+\cdots+\frac{f^{(N)}(x_0)}{N !}(x-x_0)^{N} + R_N,
\end{equation}
where $R_N$ is the remainder term of this $N$-th order Taylor polynomial.

However, I feel a bit confusion that whether we have
\begin{equation}
\left|\frac{f^{(N)}(x_0)}{N !}(x-x_0)^{N}\right| > |R_n|.
\end{equation}
I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: For $x$ close enough to $x_0$, this is true.  Consider the limit as $x$ approaches $x_0$.

Comment: I think it is true if $\lim_{x \to x_0}$. But if $x$ is not close enough to $x_0$, is this inequality still held?

Comment: No, not necessarily.

Comment: Of course not if $x$ is not required to be close enough to $x_0$. Taylor series only inform you about the local behaviour of the function, near $x_0$.

Comment: If $f^n(x_0)=0$ it is not true in general, since you may still have $R_n\neq 0$. Only if $f^n(x_0)\neq 0$ you have an order relation, only for $x$ sufficiently close to $x_0$ (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$R_n$ and the last term are not related in any specific way, it depends on the specific function. The only thing that is true in general is that $R_n$ is an infinitesimal of order higher than the order of the last term, that is
$$
R_n(x)=o(|x-x_0|^n)
$$
as $x\to x_0$. In other words, when $f^n(x_0)\neq 0$ you have $R_n(x)<< \textrm{last term}$ in the asymptotic sense.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to exactly say how sufficiently close from $x$ to $x_0$, we could have this inequality?

Comment: Well.. you can use Lagrange's form of the remainder. Suppose you know that $|f^{(n+1)}|\le M$ on the interval between $x_0$ and $x$. Then you know that $|R_n(x)|\le M(x-x^0)^{(n+1)}$ and you have $|R_n(x)|\le\textrm{last term}$ when $|x-x_0|\le(n+1)f^n(x_0)/M$.

Comment: I got it, thank you.